# Promise of something would happen as reported speech

Tags: indirect-speech

He promised the following: “your payment will reach your account next Friday”. How to phrase the message below correctly?

```
The payment you promised to make reach my account a week ago has still not arrived.
The payment you promised to      reach my account a week ago has still not arrived.
The payment you promised would   reach my account a week ago has still not arrived.
The payment you promised to will reach my account a week ago has still not arrived.
```

Comment: Are you paying by the word? You should include more markers to make yourself clear. "A week ago you promised that the payment would reach my account next Friday. However, as of today, `N` days later, it has not arrived."

Comment: @JohnLawler: No, I'm not. I'm trying to find out if a sentence can be phrased in a particular way in English.

Comment: If you want the rule for a particular construction (and there are rules), you hafta identify the construction; just changing words at random doesn't give much information, especially if you don't know the rules by which they're created.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'm glad that more helpful users exists here too, you should follow the example of Smartish_Girl.

Comment: You just want a quick answer to your own question, you don't want to understand why it's the answer, you can't be bothered to be clear, and you won't know the answer the next time it comes up. Right? OK. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct option would be the third one, with a little change:

The payment that you promised would reach my account a week ago has still not arrived.